# Should the ACF or the PACF be used to evaluate autocorrelation of regression errors?

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, residuals, independence

Regression texts (like [this one](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/5/4), for instance) suggest using acf plots of the model residuals to evaluate whether the model errors are independent when the dependent variable consists of time-series data.

My question is should the ACF or the PACF be used to evaluate autocorrelation of the errors?

Comment: Comment as I'm not 100% sure of the answer but from my uni notes- ACF is used to detect moving-average, PACF is used to detect autoregression either should be able to detect whether there is time dependence on the data. I would recommend looking up the white noise test.